# Angular.js accessing and displaying nested models efficiently

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs, relational-database

I'm building a site at the moment where there are many relational links between data. As an example, users can make `bookings`, which will have `booker` and `bookee`, along with an array of `messages` which can be attached to a `booking`.

An example json would be...

```
booking = {
  id: 1,
  location: 'POST CDE',
  desc: "Awesome stackoverflow description."
  booker: {
    id: 1, fname: 'Lawrence', lname: 'Jones',
  },
  bookee: {
    id: 2, fname: 'Stack', lname: 'Overflow',
  },
  messages: [
    { id: 1, mssg: 'For illustration only' }
  ]
}
```

Now my question is, how would you model this data in your angular app? And, while very much related, how would you pull it from the server?

As I can see it I have a few options.

#### Pull everything from the server at once

Here I would rely on the server to serialize the nested data and just use the given json object. Downsides are that I don't know what users will be involved when requesting a booking or similar object, so I can't cache them and I'll therefore be pulling a large chunk of data every time I request.

#### Pull the booking with booker/bookee as user `ids`

For this I would use promises for my data models, and have the server return an object such as...

```
booking = {
  id: 1,
  location: 'POST CDE',
  desc: "Awesome stackoverflow description."
  booker: 1, bookee: 2,
  messages: [1]
}
```

Which I would then pass to a `Booking` constructor, which would resolve the relevant (`booker`,`bookee` and `message`) ids into data objects via their respective factories.

The disadvantages here are that many ajax requests are used for a single booking request, though it gives me the ability to cache user/message information.

---

In summary, is it better practise to rely on a single ajax request to collect all the nested information at once, or rely on various requests to 'flesh out' the initial response after the fact.

I'm using Rails 4 if that helps (maybe Rails would be more suited to a single request?)

Comment: I see someones voted to close the question, if you could let me know what I can do to improve it then that would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is a little to broad, that's why? You also haven't stated your stack.

Comment: I assumed stating a stack seems a bit redundant as the issue here is clientside and related to general http transfers. Seeing as it's about ajax'ing data via a RESTFul interface I assumed it wouldn't be required. But you're right, I'll try to make it more specific.

Comment: Use ngResource to get the data, its what you need by the sounds of it. Also check out this tutorial -> https://shellycloud.com/blog/2013/10/how-to-integrate-angularjs-with-rails-4. If there are any more questions feel free to ask, I have just done the same sort of thing on the same stack.

Comment: Use one request too, with `Active Model Serializers` is really easy to nest the data and then create relational objects when you get it with Angular.

Comment: @Doi thanks for that link, it's got some great information. Found an even better link in it's comments as well. I think I'm going to go with a combination of both the id resolution and serialization, in that I'll write it now to analyse whether the class has any id keys that are strings, and if they are then I'll resolve them, else I'll assume they've been serialized. I figure this gives me the flexibility for caching etc. If I find it works effectively I'll answer this question with what I've got. Thanks again!

Comment: Pleasure! Remember to keep it simple, the solution you're looking for is simpler than you think!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use a system where I can hopefully have the best of both worlds, by creating a base class for all my resources that will be given a custom `resolve` function, that will know what fields in that particular class may require resolving. A sample resource function would look like this...

```
class Booking
  # other methods...
  resolve: ->
    booking = this
    User
      .query(booking.booker, booking.bookee)
      .then (users) ->
        [booking.booker, booking.bookee] = users
```

Where it will pass the value of the `booker` and `bookee` fields to the `User` factory, which will have a constructor like so...

```
class User
  # other methods
  constructor: (data) ->
    user = this
    if not isNaN(id = parseInt data, 10)
      User.get(data).then (data) ->
        angular.extend user, data
    else angular.extend this, data
```

If I have passed the `User` constructor a value that cannot be parsed into a number (so this will happily take string `ids` as well as numerical) then it will use the `User` factorys `get` function to retrieve the data from the server (or through a caching system, implementation is obviously inside the `get` function itself). If however the value is detected to be non-NaN, then I'll assume that the User has already been serialized and just extend this with the value.

So it's invisible in how it caches and is independent of how the server returns the nested objects. Allows for modular ajax requests and avoids having to redownload unnecessary data via its caching system.

Once everything is up and running I'll write some tests to see whether the application would be better served with larger, chunked ajax requests or smaller modular ones like above. Either way this lets you pass all model data through your angular factories, so you can rely on every record having inherited any prototype methods you may want to use.